# not entering into save function in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am newbie to node js and mongoose and unable to save the record in the mongoose I am using Mongodb atlas I have tried several ways to debug and tried different things but not getting save or not able enter into the inside the save function. so not able to handle the save callback in moongose If try to hit request in postman its not getting the response it getting blocked and not entering into save so  Thanks in Advance

controller.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/users');


exports.registerUser = (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const user = new User({
        _id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email
    });
    user.save(function(err) {
        console.log("Callback");
        if (err) { 
            console.log("error");
            res.json({message: err});
        }
        else{
            res.json({ message: 'User created' });
        }
    })
}
```

router.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/users');


exports.registerUser = (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const user = new User({
        _id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email
    });
    user.save(function(err) {
        console.log("Callback");
        if (err) { 
            console.log("error");
            res.json({message: err});
        }
        else{
            res.json({ message: 'User created' });
        }
    })
}
```

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/users');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;



const uri = "mongodb+srv://<connection string>/admin";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req,res,next )=>{
    console.log(req);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
        return res.status(200).json({});
      }
      next();
});

app.use('/', userRoutes);

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    const error = new Error('Not Found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((error,req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error:{
            message: error.message
        }
    })
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure mongoose is using any connections? Seems like you connected to server with `mongodb` module instead. See the [Getting Started](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) docs on how to connect with mongoose.

Comment: If I am using mongoose i getting the following error its deprecated and use mongoClient.connect  If am using mongodb then there will be lot of implementation changes can u help me out